# remove ascii character and replace with non-ascii

Tags: ascii, non-ascii-characters, extended-ascii

I want to remove one ASCII character and then I  want replace it with non-ASCII. My code is :

```
sed -e 's/[\d100\d130]/g'
```

To explain: I want to replace "100" (in ASCII ,decimal ) with "135" (in ASCII, decimal.) In short, I want to replace 2 letters and one of them will remove. This code is valid?

Comment: Use `tr`: `tr '\144' '\206'`.

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried. @gniourf_gniourf

Comment: What does _It doesn't work_ mean? (do you get an error? aren't the `d` replaced?)

Comment: d isn't replaced .@gniourf_gniourf

Comment: (Apart from the obvious typo—it should be `tr '\144' '\207'`—see Thomas Dickey's answer). This is not going to _edit_ your file… is this what you're expecting?

Comment: when I tried all letters , my output : abc�efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~�������������  @gniourf_gniourf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decimal 100 is a "d", and 135 is an extended ascii "ç" or cedilla.
Setting a to all values:

```
a="$(printf "$(printf '\\x%x' {95..105} 135 135 135 {130..140} )")"
```

Both this work:

```
echo "$a"| tr '\144' '\207'
echo "$a"| sed -e $'s/\144/\207/g'    # Note the $
```

If you want to see this characters, write to a file, and open it with encoding IBM850. In an text editor with that capacity you will see (three times a cedilla ç, and the d changed as well):

```
_`abcçefghiçççéâäàåçêëèïî
```

---

#### UTF-8

For utf-8, things are diferent.
The cedilla in UTF-8 is decimal 231 (hex E7), and it is output with this:

```
$ printf $'\U0E7'
ç
```

To get the UTF-8 of values above 127 (7F) and up to 255 (FF) may get tricky because Bash misinterprets some values. This function will allow the conversion from a value to the correct character:

```
function chr_utf8 {
    local val
    [[ ${2?Missing Ordinal Value} -lt 0x80000000 ]] || return 1

    if [[ ${2} -lt 0x100 && ${2} -ge 0x80 ]]; then

        # bash 4.2 incorrectly encodes
        # \U000000ff as \xff so encode manually
        printf -v val "\\%03o\%03o" $(( (${2}>>6)|0xc0 )) $(( (${2}&0x3f)|0x80 ))
    else
        printf -v val '\\U%08x' "${2}"
    fi
    printf -v ${1?Missing Dest Variable} ${val}
}

chr_utf8 a 231
echo "$a"
```

---

### Conclusion

The solution was actually very simple:

```
echo "aadddcc" | sed $'s/d/\U0E7/g'       # echo $'\U0E7' should output ç
aaçççcc
```

Test that you get a ç from `echo $'\U0E7'`, if not, you need the function above.

Comment: when I tried all letters my output :  abc�efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~�������������

Comment: Do you need a cedilla?, that is [utf-8 decimal 231](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e7/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid sed command:

```
sed -e 's/[\d100\d135]/g'
```

Perhaps something like

```
sed -e 's/[\d100]/[\d135]/g'
```

In a quick test, this "works":

```
echo 'd' | sed -e 's/[\d100]/[\d135]/g'
```

The suggested tr command is close, but 135 translates to octal 207, e.g,

```
tr '\144' '\207'
```

In a UTF-8 system, you likely will run into problems with 135, since it is not a valid single-byte code as such.  The corresponding UTF-8 encoding for 135 uses two bytes, e.g., \302\207

```
echo 'd' | sed -e 's/\d100/\d194\d135/g'
```

might be what OP intended.  With my locale `en_US.UTF-8`, it produces a UTF-8 encoded 135 (which shows up in vi-like-emacs as `\u0087`: this happens to be valid *UTF-8*, but not a printable character since it is actually a control character in Unicode).  Given more information about what OP intended for the output, better advice can be offered.

Comment: When I run, my output is "? ". Why ?

Comment: In the rhs of the `s///` operator, I'm not sure OP wants the square brackets; and they are useless in the lhs too: `s/\d100/\d135/g`.

Comment: As I said: in UTF-8 that is not a valid character.   I left the square brackets, but agree they are unnecessary.

Comment: It still doesn't excepted from my OP. :/

Comment: when I tried all letters , my output : abc�efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~�������������